# Finding AIC and BIC for GEV using R

Tags: r, statistics

How to find the AIC and BIC for GEV after finding its parameter using L-moments?

```
#Load data
library(quantmod)
getSymbols(c("BTC-USD","ETH-USD"), from="2020-05-01", to="2022-05-31", src="yahoo", periodicity="daily")

`BTC-USD`$BTC.r<-diff(log(`BTC-USD`$`BTC-USD.Adjusted`))
`BTC-USD`$BTC.r[1]=0

#Converting the xts object to a dataframe and processing dates
`BTC-USD`$Date1<-rownames(`BTC-USD`)
BTC<-data.frame(date=index(`BTC-USD`),coredata(`BTC-USD`))
BTC$date<-as.POSIXct(BTC$date)
BTC$mo<-strftime(BTC$date,"%m")
BTC$yr<-strftime(BTC$date,"%Y")

#Block Maxima - Generalized Extreme Value distribution
library(extRemes)
extrema1<- setDT(BTC)[,.(BTC_down = -min(BTC.r)),by=.(yr,mo)]

# fitting of GEV distribution based on L-moments estimation
fit_lmom_1 <- fevd(as.vector(extrema1$BTC_down), method = "Lmoments", type="GEV")
```

I have find the parameters, but I'm not sure on how to find the AIC and BIC.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have provided the complete code.